# Trying to kill a windows service and then restart it with a batch file

Tags: windows-services, batch-file

Im trying to kill a windows service and then restart it using just a batch file.

I tried using the following code

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq \SYSTEM" /IM NoDinero.exe
```

And was given this message:

> "no tasks running w the specified
>   criteria"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop a service: `NET STOP "Service Name"`

Start a service: `NET START "Service Name"`

Comment: I tried: 

NET STOP NoDinero.exe 

but was given a message saying :
The Service name is invalid. More help is avaialable by Typing NET HELPMSG 2185

Comment: You don't use the exe name, but the name of the service (Run services.msc and check the properties for the service)